# Java Spring with H2 database, slow spring start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Spring boot start becomes very slow when H2 database becomes 50MB and more, is there any way to speed up the start process?

- 2018-06-28 17:55:15.515  INFO 23632 --- [  restartedMain]
  io.onetouch.SpringBootStarter            : Starting SpringBootStarter
  on...
- 2018-06-28 17:55:15.516  INFO 23632 --- [  restartedMain]
  io.onetouch.SpringBootStarter            : No active profile set...
- 2018-06-28 17:55:15.582  INFO 23632 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context...
- 2018-06-28 ***17:55:19.403***  INFO 23632 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
- 2018-06-28 **17:59:58.589**  INFO 23632 --- [  restartedMain]
  trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'connectionFactory'
  of type [io.onetouch.persistance.ConnectionFactory] is not eligible
  for ...

Comment: How is your h2 database connection?

Comment: datasource.url = jdbc:h2:${datasource.folder}/test_db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
datasource.username = *****
datasource.password = ******
datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: Are you recreating the database on each start? This database is used for integration testing?

Comment: not recreating, only updating

Answer (score 1):

In my experience H2 has worked great for small embedded databases. At some point, though (300 MB in my case) it became increasingly slow and I was forced to replace it for a non-embedded one -- PostgreSQL -- that solved all these problems. This solution was available to me since an embedded database was not a hard requirement for me.

Having said that, a 50 MB database is not that big. It used to be, but current machines should support this size pretty well. Maybe the machine itself is a small one, or maybe it's overwhelmed in terms of CPU or memory?